# [SQL]How to return rows of a list of items that has their individual max date?

Tags: mysql, groupwise-maximum

Currently I have a list of strings, let's say  ('A,'B','C','D','E'), and say there is a table that has multiple dates associated with these strings.

IE table looks something like this.

```
String     Dates
A         Jan 1
A         Feb 1 
A         Mar 1
B         Dec 1
B         Oct 1
B         Jan 1
C         Jan 1
C         Oct 1
C         Nov 1
D         Jan 1
D         Feb 1
D         Apr 1
E         Apr 1
E         Mar 1
E         Oct 1
```

And I want to just have rows that have the max date, but of each String only one time.
IE:

```
String     Dates
A         Mar 1
B         Dec 1
C         Nov 1
D         Apr 1
E         Oct 1
```

Currently, I have a bunch of unions.  It works, but I feel like there should be a faster way to do what Im doing.

```
select * from table where String = 'A' and Dates = (select max(Dates) from table where String = 'A' )
union all
select * from table where String = 'B' and Dates = (select max(Dates) from table where String = 'B' )
union all
select * from table where String = 'C' and Dates = (select max(Dates) from table where String = 'C' )
union all
select * from table where String = 'D' and Dates = (select max(Dates) from table where String = 'D' )
union all
select * from table where String = 'E' and Dates = (select max(Dates) from table where String = 'E' )
```

Comment: Are you dates Proper `DATE` or `DATETIME` columns or these strings?

Comment: Please dont show us PSEUDO code, (something like) show us what is really in the table

Comment: See the tag I added.

Answer (score 0):

We can use max and group by as below. As there are no values in the table which are not in the list we could leave out the line `where id in  ('A','B','C','D','E')`

```
select
  id, 
  max(day)
from StringDates
where id in  ('A','B','C','D','E')
group by id
order by id;
```

```
id | max(day)  
:- | :---------
A  | 2022-03-01
B  | 2022-12-01
C  | 2022-11-01
D  | 2022-04-01
E  | 2022-10-01
```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_5.7&fiddle=b80df1c904266a5ed3bed745aa639839)*

Comment: Thanks! Let me try that on my query!